# coreData existing validation

Tags: ios, validation, core-data, uitextfield

so I'm doing application form using CoreData
First I'm creating "Shop" with unique name and some properties.
In application you can edit that "Shop", and I'm trying to make validation by "shopName" to avoid a creation another "Shop" with same name.
I'm using this:

```
    -(BOOL)uniqueEntityExistsWithEnityName {

    BOOL returnValue = NO;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Shop"];

    NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"shopName = [cd] %@", _shopName.text];

    NSSortDescriptor *shop = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"shopName" ascending:YES];

    [request setSortDescriptors: @[shop]];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *matches = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    NSLog(@"request = %@",predicate);

    if (!matches) {
        NSLog(@"Error: Couldn't execute fetch request %@", error);

    }
    else if([matches count] > 1) {

        NSString *existShop = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Could Be Only One %@ Shop", _shopName.text];

        UIAlertView *exist = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Shop Exists in Your Records"
                                                       message:existShop
                                                      delegate:nil
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [exist show];

        NSLog(@"Error: Have more than %lu records",
              (unsigned long)[matches count]);
        returnValue = YES;
    }
    else {

        NSLog(@"%lu object in record", (unsigned long)[matches count]);

        [self oldShopDelete];
        [self checkShopPhoneNumber];

        editShop.shopName = _shopName.text;
        editShop.shopPhoneNumber = _shopPhoneNumber.text;
        editShop.shopSecondPhoneNumber = _shopSecondPhoneNumber.text;
        editShop.shopEmail = _shopEmail.text;
        editShop.shopNote = _shopNoteView.text;

        [super saveAndDissmiss];

        returnValue = YES;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

With that code you still have opportunity to save one more edited "Shop" with same name.
But the thing is - I can not make `[matches count] = 1` after this I'll no chance to edit that Shop

Maybe there are another way to do such validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for a name clash only when the Name is actually being set for the first time or edited.

You can also pass the current shop into the predicate to ensure `AND SELF != %@` so there will be no match with an existing shop being edited but with an unchanged name.

Comment: Is it have to looks like this? '[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"shopName = [cd] %@ AND SELF != %@", _shopName.text, _shopName.text]'

Comment: No, the second part is the whole shop you're editing, possibly `editShop` from the code you show.

Comment: genius! that's why I was confused)))